# Generating PKCS7 encoded digital signature - Hwcrypto, itextPdf, USB Token

Tags: java, grails, itext

I'm trying to sign a pdf document on the Java webapp running on the server, I have used hwcrypto.js and was able to successfully get the signature as well as the certificate. Now I'm trying to generate a pkcs7 encoded CMS signed data using below code:

```
String generatePkcs7EncodedSignature(String certString, String signature) {
    try {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder()
        byte[] signatureByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(signature)

        List<Certificate> certList = getPublicCertificates(certString)
        Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList)
        CMSProcessableByteArray msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(signatureByte)
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator()
        gen.addCertificates(certs)
        CMSSignedData data = gen.generate(msg, true)
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data.getEncoded())
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        println(ex.stackTrace)
    }
    return null
}
```

getPublicCertificates method is as follows:

```
X509Certificate getPublicCertificate(String certificateString)
            throws IOException, CertificateException {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
        Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is)
        return cert
    }
```

But I'm getting "No Certificate to validate signature" error when I open the pdf in Adobe Reader
[image]